# How do I adapt the look and feel of existing Tk apps using TTk?

Tags: toolkit

[slebetman says:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3837938#3838057)

> But Tk is only really ugly on Unixen because it defaults to a Motif theme (modern Tk is/should be replaced by TTk which is themeable).

Given two Tk apps which I still use occasionally, namely Gitk and ptkdb, how do I change their look and feel so that it matches the rest of the desktop environment (KDE 4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://wiki.tcl.tk/gtklook.tcl for a quick way to make default Tk look less painfully ugly. I often use it in my own programs to hide the fact that it's actually written in tcl/tk.

The code given is tcl but you can easily use the options in an Xresources or Xdefaults file which I think should work in other languages as well. Or, it that doesn't work I believe there is an equivalent `option` method in Perl/Tk*.

Yes, the changes are not much. Basically just reducing pixel widths of things like borders and scrollbars. But it does look much nicer.

*note: I only mention Perl/Tk because you mentioned it in another post. As for modifying gitk, it is written in tcl so you can easily copy-paste the code somewhere.

Comment: In `gitk` after `package require Tk` I added `lappend auto_path /home/daxim/local/share/tcl-style␤package require style␤style::use as` (also tried: `style::use lobster`), but it made no difference at all. Anyway, this requires so much Tcl programming for each single program and I don't want to do that. I had hoped to instead just set GUI options somewhere or change a config files so it takes place globally. I accept you *pro forma*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [TkDocs website](http://www.tkdocs.com/), everything I know about modern Tk I learnt from there! Well and experience too of course ;-)

It will not be simple to retrofit it onto a substantial legacy application, but you could probably get surprisingly far by just prefixing the widgets with `ttk::`.

Comment: That's disappointing to learn. I tested out what you said by substituting `Tk::` with `Tkx::` in ptkdb, but it won't run anymore because the API difference is greater than that. If a rewrite is necessary, then one might as well pick a mainstream toolkit. I'll leave the question open in case someone knows a solution that does not involve programming to that great extent.